# How do you use the jquery 'load' method to load a page fragment when passing a variable?

Tags: jquery, ajax, load, parameter-passing

Not sure if this has been asked, but here it goes, given the following code...

```
$('#infoPane').load('showInfo.php #info');
```

How do a pass variable to the page yet only just load the page fragment?

```
$('#imgPane').load('showInfo.php?q='+$q+ '#picture');
```

The above code does not work so any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably doesn't work because the spacing is incorrect:

```
$('#imgPane').load('showInfo.php?q='+$q+' #picture');
```

In your example, you're trying to load: `showInfo.php?q=whatever#picture` rather than `showInfo.php?q=whatever #picture`

However, you should be able to post data to your script similar to the following:

```
$('#imgPane').load('showInfo.php #picture', { 'q' : $q });
```

Passing data is one of the jQuery [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) parameters.

Comment: yeah i figured that might be the case, cheers. I've only really done it the old fashioned javascript way before

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how jQuery works here, exactly, but using the URL hash as ID seems odd. It should probably look like this:

```
$('#imgPane').load('showInfo.php?q='+$q+' #picture');
```

Answer (score 0):

The resulting URL does not follow the "magic" syntax: `<url> #<id-of-fragment-to-load>`, but comes out as `showInfo.php?q=<value-of-$q>#picture` (no space). Try:

```
$('#imgPane').load('showInfo.php?q='+$q+' #picture');
```

Alternatively, did you try passing the value via the second argument (`data`)?

```
$('#imgPane').load('showInfo.php #picture', {q: $q});
```